# Django REST: Automatically update connected model (After POST request)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to create an ability for users to exchange 1-to-1 messages. To do this, I would like to update fields in my Django models, depending on actions taken by the `Message` model. For example, I would like to update the `last_message` in `Conversation` model, each time a new message is posted.

I have 2 main models: `Conversation` and `Message`, where each conversation can have many messages.

**Models.py**

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    last_message = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

class Message(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I figured that I need to use the override the `save()` method in the `Message` class. Or possibly the `save()` method of serialiser.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Message, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    # something that I need
    self.conversation.last_message = self.body
```

In the end, I would like to send a POST request to my API endpoint e.g.
`/api/conversation/<id>/messages/` and it will update the `Conversation` object with every new latest message.

Comment: It's not clear what is your problem. You are right you can override save method. Does it work?

Comment: `POST /api/conversation/<id>/messages/` successfully creates the message, but this message is not put in the `Conversation.last_message`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed to call conversation's `save` method. Since you need to update conversation only for new message I think better to override serializer's `create` method:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    your code
    ...
    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        instance.conversation.last_message = instance.body
        instance.conversation.save() # Need to update conversation in DB  
        return instance
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. Also using serializers instead of models